# Multiple pointers to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Looking through a projects code I found this:

```
font.Draw(x, y + 15 * 1, fontColor, "agPtr: %p <= %p", *(void**)agLocked.m_ptr, (void**)agLocked.m_ptr);
```

How is `*(void**)agLocked.m_ptr`

Different than `(void**)agLocked.m_ptr`?

Also this:

```
unsigned long shift = *(unsigned long*)all.m_ptr;
    shift = *(unsigned long*)(shift + 0x30);
    shift = *(unsigned long*)(shift + 0x28);
    shift = *(unsigned long*)(shift + 0x178);
```

I have looked at pointer arithmetic and all that and it doesn't make sense to me. Can someone point (heh) me in the right direction? is the first `*(void**)` accessing three pointers? why not use `(void***)`? While I am comfortable with c++ I would like to better understand the above so that I can contribute to the project.

Comment: The result of `*(void**)` is `(void*)`. It deferences the pointer by one level. The result of `*(unsigned long*)` is `unsigned long`.

Comment: `type* something` declares a pointer to a `type`, `*something` dereferences that pointer.

Comment: As for the `unsigned long` stuff: the pointer arithmetic depends somewhat on the type of `all.m_ptr`.  And there's a good chance that the code will cause the program to crash on many platforms.

Answer (score 2):

```
*(void**)agLocked.m_ptr
```

This dereferences `agLocked.m_ptr` to get a `void *` and will probably fault if it's `NULL` or contains junk.

```
(void**)agLocked.m_ptr
```

This just casts `agLocks.m_ptr` to a `void **`.